# In pandas how to delete columns in a numerical sequence?

Tags: python, pandas

In python 3 and pandas I have the dataframe:

```
informacao1.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 36 columns):
uf_x                               5 non-null object
cargo                              5 non-null object
nome_completo_x                    5 non-null object
sequencial                         5 non-null object
numero_urna                        5 non-null int64
cpf                                5 non-null object
nome_urna                          5 non-null object
situacao_cand                      5 non-null object
partido_eleicao                    5 non-null object
ocupacao                           5 non-null object
data_nascimento                    5 non-null object
nome                               5 non-null object
nome_completo_y                    5 non-null object
partido                            5 non-null object
uf_y                               5 non-null object
cargo_parlamentar                  5 non-null object
tipo                               5 non-null object
classe                             5 non-null object
numero                             5 non-null int64
único                              5 non-null object
assunto                            5 non-null object
data_inicial                       5 non-null object
data_final                         5 non-null object
andamento                          5 non-null object
link                               5 non-null object
transparencia                      5 non-null object
conferencia                        5 non-null object
data_conferencia                   5 non-null object
resumo                             5 non-null object
observacao                         5 non-null object
link_noticia_tribunal_confiavel    3 non-null object
interessa                          5 non-null object
ministro_relator                   5 non-null object
processo_conectado                 0 non-null object
situacao                           5 non-null object
cadastro_push                      5 non-null object
dtypes: int64(2), object(34)
memory usage: 1.4+ KB
```

I need to delete all the columns, from the eleventh (counting the first as zero): then delete the nome, nome_completo_y, partido, (...), situacao and cadastro_push

And keep only the first ten: uf_x, cargo, nome_completo_x, sequencial, numero_urna, cpf, nome_urna, situacao_cand, partido_eleicao, ocupacao and data_nascimento

Please, is there a way to delete columns in a sequence?

Comment: Try `df.iloc[:,:11]` .

Comment: This way? informacao1.drop([informacao1.columns[[:,:11]], axis=1, inplace=True)

Comment: Just `informacao1.iloc[:,:11]`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll save it as a new dataframe